# BinaryWriter in loop causes "file is being used by another process" error even though it is closed and 'using'

Tags: c#

Title sais it all really.

```
private bool addToBinary(byte[] msg, string filepath)
{
    bool succ = false;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
                {
                    bw.Write(msg);

                    bw.Flush();
                    fileStream.Flush();
                    bw.Close();
                }
            }
            succ = true;
        }
        catch (IOException ex) { Console.WriteLine("Write Exception (addToBinary) : " + ex.Message); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Some Exception occured (addToBinary) : " + ex.Message); return false; }
    } while (!succ);
    return true;
}
```

(bw.close also closes the underlying stream)

Using this in any loop causes an output such as;

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Write Exception (addToBinary) : The process cannot access the file 'C:\test\test.png' because it is being used by another process.
```

The bigger the file gets, the more of these errors pop up. It does get through eventually but it significantly reduces file writing speed. It's the `Stream fileStream =` bit that causes the exception.

What did I do wrong?

Example usage;

```
do
{
    serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    bytesRead = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize); //How many bytes did we just read from the stream?

    recstrbytes = new byte[bytesRead]; //Final byte array
    Array.Copy(inStream, recstrbytes, bytesRead); //Copy from inStream to the final byte array
    addToBinary(recstrbytes, @"C:\test\test.png"); //Append final byte array to binary
    received += recstrbytes.Length; //Increment bytes received
}while (received < filesize);
```

Comment: Using the `BinaryWriter` here is wrong and there is no need to use it either.

Comment: @leppie Removing the binary writer and doing `fileStream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length); fileStream.Flush(); fileStream.Close();` has the same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first check if you can access the file before using Stream to read the file.

You can have a look at this link :

[Best way to handle errors when opening file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503884/best-way-to-handle-errors-when-opening-file)

Have a look at the answers
Although I posted my answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9503939/448407  but you can look at the post marked as answer.

Only read the file contents if you can access the file and I think it will then work.

Comment: Looks like I need to buffer the data in the memory before writing it to disk to prevent antivirus from scanning it all the time.. I hope there's an alternative, but I'll open another question for that since it's not related.

Comment: @natli that's an interesting issue you have there.

Answer (score 1):

Some good advice style wise for those stacked using statements. When you start using more than one it is often neater to use the following style:

```
using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
{
    bw.Write(msg);
    bw.Flush();
    fileStream.Flush();
    bw.Close();
}
```

I'm afraid I can't solve your question though, but I'm not sure how much of a good an idea it is to repeatedly try and write to the stream if it isn't successful the first time round.

Comment: `but I'm not sure how much of a good an idea it is to repeatedly try and write to the stream if it isn't successful the first time round.` It's not a good idea at all, but I ran into this issue so I didn't get to write proper error handling yet ;)